# Installing video4linux Beaglebone

Tags: ssh, beagleboneblack, video4linux

I'm working on Beaglebone black on a project on image processing. For this purpose, I shall need video4linux application.

However, I'm not able to share my internet with the beaglebone because of which "sudo apt-get install v4l-utils" isn't working. Whenever I change the internet sharing settings, I'm unable to ssh into the local ip of the beaglebone.

Hence, I want a method where I can install video4linux without internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be very complicated if you want install package without internet as you need to install all the dependent package before the actual package.
Each package have dependency of other package.

Still you can download the package from :[v4l-utils](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/v4l-utils/v4l-utils_1.14.2-1_armhf.deb)

And using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) tool you can copy in Beagle-bone.

Other dependent package for debian you can find at:[Debian Packages](https://packages.debian.org)

Comment: You can also share internet from your host to beagle-bone via USB. Follow this steps:

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I had worked out on how to share internet with beaglebone and it worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also share internet from your host to beagle-bone via USB.

Follow this sh code:
On the BeagleBone

```
ifconfig usb0 192.168.7.2
route add default gw 192.168.7.1
```

On Linux computer:

```
sudo su
#eth0 is my internet facing interface, eth3 is the BeagleBone USB connection
ifconfig eth3 192.168.7.1
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth3 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```